# Best model for variable selection with big data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I posted a question earlier about some code but now I realize I should be more broad with the general idea. Basically, I'm trying to build a statistical model with about 1000 observations and 2000 variables. I would like to determine which variables are most influential in effecting my dependent variable with high significance. I don't plan to use the model for prediction, just for variable selection. My independent variables are binary and dependent variable is continuous. I've tried multiple linear regression and fixed models with tools such as statsmodels and scikit-learn. However, I have encountered issues such as having more variables than observations. I would prefer to solve the problem in python since I have basic knowledge in it. However, stats is very new to me so I don't know the best direction. Any help is appreciated.

Tree method

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import preprocessing

data=pd.read_excel('data_file.xlsx')

y=data.iloc[:, -1]
X=data.iloc[:, :-1]

le=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y=le.fit_transform(y)

clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf=clf.fit(X,y)

tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file='tree.dot')
```

Or if I output to text file, the first few lines are:

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box] ;
0 [label="X[685] <= 0.5\ngini = 0.995\nsamples = 1097\nvalue = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1\n1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1\n1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1\n1, 7, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 6, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1\n1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2\n11, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1\n1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1\n4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2\n1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3\n1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 11\n1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 5, 21, 1, 1\n11, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 15, 3, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1\n17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4\n1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1\n3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1\n1, 2, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2\n1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 13, 2\n1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n9, 1, 2, 5, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9, 2, 2, 13, 1\n1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3\n1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1\n4, 1, 2, 3, 3]"] ;
1 [label="X[990] <= 0.5\ngini = 0.995\nsamples = 1040\nvalue = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1\n1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 30, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1\n1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1\n1, 7, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n6, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 6, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1\n1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2\n11, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1\n1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n6, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1\n4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2\n1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3\n1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11\n1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 5, 21, 1, 1\n1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 15, 3, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1\n1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1\n16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4\n1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1\n1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1\n3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1\n1, 2, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2\n1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0\n1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3\n1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2\n1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\n9, 1, 2, 5, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9, 2, 2, 13, 1\n1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3\n1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1\n4, 1, 0, 3, 3]"] ;
```

Comment: Look at the averages of the dependent variable over the groups of your independent variables. Or you can look into ANOVA methods

Comment: You could try training decision trees and look at which variables are used in your tree uses.

Comment: @FatihAkici what do you mean exactly do you mean by dependent variable one groups of independent variable. Also do you know a good tool to implement the ANOVA method for big data, that will also give p values?

Comment: @vlemaistre is there a good tool for decision trees? What exactly would that do in this context

Comment: Use skikit learn to build a decision tree. Look at how those are created but to sum it up : at each leaf the population is divided in two using the variable that divides it best concerning your variable to predict. As such you can make the assumption that the variables used in your tree (the ones higher up in your tree in preference) are the most influential

Comment: Yeah, tree-based methods would work perfectly as well. Scikit's trees or random forests would be ideal. And by the way, 1000 observations and 2000 variables is not big data. If you can open the CSV containing it, it is definitely not big data.

Comment: Ok I will try the tree method for now, then. I guess the most influential variables will also have high significance? Can I see p values for each variable somehow? And yeah I guess it’s not really big data. It was too big for JMP at least

Comment: I did the tree method. But I can't get the file open, maybe because it is 3MB as a .dot file and 10MB as a .ps file. Is there an effective way to visualize the tree? If I output as a string, are the variables in order of importance? I added the code I used and the string output.

Comment: Are the variables at the top of the tree the most important? Or the ones that always return true at the bottom of the tree?

Answer (score 0):

**1.Variante A: Feature Selection Scikit**

For future selection `scikit`offers a lot of different approaches:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

Here it sumps up the comments from above.

**2.Variante B: Feature Selection with linear regression**

You can also read your feature importance if you run linearregression on it. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html .The function `reg.coef_`will give you the coefiecents for your futres, the higher the absolute number is, the more important is your feature, so for exmaple 0.8 is a really important future, where 0.00001 is not important.

**3.Variante C: PCA (not for binary case)**

Why you wanna kill your variables ? I would recommend you to use: PCA - Principal ocmponent analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis.

The basic concept is to transform your 2000 features to a smaller space (maybe 1000 or whatever), while still being mathematically useful.

`Scikik-learn`has a good package for it: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: Does it narrow it down to 1000 features, and change the 2000 features into 1000 new features? If it's new features, can this somehow tell me which of the 2000 features are most important?(after using multiple linear regression, for example)

Comment: I will not recommend PCA for dimensionality reduction because it transforms the original variable. This causes an EXPLODED variable count. The OP said there are 2000 variables. PCA will explode this count to greater than 2000 variables! Moreover PCA is for continuous data. And binary is NOT continuous.. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting closer look to variance of your variables ot keep those with the largest range (`pandas.DataFrame.var()`) and eliminate those variables which correlate at most with others (`pandas.DataFrame.corr()`), as further steps I'd suggest to get any methods mentioned earlier.